# Can a mounted fighter with a Lance and another weapon benefit from the Dual Wielding feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, mounted-combat

The rules stipulate that you must use two hands to wield a Lance when on foot (but you can use it with one hand while mounted).

The Dual Wielder feat gives benefits to those who use two non-light **one-handed weapons**.

If you are mounted with a Lance in one hand and another weapon in the other, can you benefit from the Dual Wielder feat ?

Comment: ...oops, sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: No worries--duplicates serve a useful purposes in providing multiple search paths to a set of answers.